# Setting up linked list class with templates?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, linked-list

I am trying to implement a linked list using a class template, however each of my classes that I want in the list all inherit from an Account class. I have attempted to template the linked list class as account however Ive come into errors I can't resolve. Any ideas as to how I can go about this?

The error exists within the customer.cpp class where it says

```
14  IntelliSense: a value of type "Account *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "CurrentAccount *"    f:\Further C++\Assignment with Templates\Assignment\Customer.cpp    22  9   Assignment
```

Customer class:

```
#ifndef CUSTOMER_H
#define CUSTOMER_H    
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"
#include "AccountLinkedList.h"

using namespace std;


class Customer
{
private:

    string name;
    string telNo;
    int doorNum;
    string street;
    string postcode;
    string sex;
    string dob;
    AccountLinkedList <Account> accountList; //Here is the linkedList templated as Account class
    Account * head;
    Account * aNode;

public:

    int customerID;
    Customer * next;

    //Customers personal details
    Customer(int id, string customerName, string gender, int doorNumber, string customerPostcode, string dateOfBirth)
        : customerID(id), name(customerName), sex(gender), doorNum(doorNumber), postcode(customerPostcode), dob(dateOfBirth)
    {

    };
    string getName();
    void addAccount(int choice);
    void showPersonDetails();
    void updatePersonDetails();
};

#endif
```

Here is the Customer.cpp file:

```
#include "Customer.h"
#include "Account.h"
#include "CurrentAccount.h"
#include "JuniorCurrentAccount.h"
#include "SavingsAccount.h"
#include "CorporateSavingsAccount.h"
#include "StudentSavingsAccount.h"
#include <string>



using namespace std;

void Customer::addAccount(int choice)
{
    int id; // temp account ID
    switch(choice)
    {
     /*Current account + JuniourCurrentAccount both inherit from Account class*/
    case 0: CurrentAccount * aNode;
            CurrentAccount * head;
                    /*the two lines below give the error on the = sign*/
            aNode = accountList.CreateNode(id/*newaccountID*/);
            head = accountList.InsertFirst(head, aNode);
            break;

    case 1: JuniorCurrentAccount * aNode;
            JuniorCurrentAccount * head;
            aNode = accountList.CreateNode(id);
            head = accountList.InsertFirst(head, aNode);
    }
}

string Customer::getName()
{
    return name;
}

void Customer::showPersonDetails()
{
    cout << name << " details" << endl;
    cout << "===============================" << endl;
    cout << "sex: " << sex << endl;
    cout << "dob: " << dob << endl;
    cout << "doorNum: " << doorNum << endl;
    cout << "postcode: " << postcode << endl;
    cout << "===============================" << endl;

}
```

Here is the current Account class that inherits from account:

```
#ifndef CURRENTACCOUNT_H
#define CURRENTACCOUNT_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Account.h"

using namespace std;

class CurrentAccount : Account
{
private:
        double intRate;
        double balance;

protected:


public:

    CurrentAccount * next;

    CurrentAccount(int accountNumber, double interestRate, double setBalance) : Account(accountNumber)
    {
        accountType = "Current Account";
        intRate = interestRate;
        balance = setBalance;
    }


};

#endif
```

Comment: I can't tell what the issue is without all the code. However, are you aware of `std::list` and (probably more appropriately) `std::vector`.

Comment: I am aware of those things, however for educational reasons I'm trying to teach myself how to handle this :) - Ive the currentAccount class code to help

Comment: `accountList.CreateNode()` returns an `Account*`, but the pointer you assign this to is of a more specific type `CustomerAccount*`. I am not sure why you do this, but that seems to be the cause of the error.

Comment: @TimOgunmakin well with respect, you certainly don't handle them like that have raw pointers to the head. If you want to write you own linked list try and copy the way in which `std::list` does it. With a well defined interface and RAII.